# How set key to variable's value using Firebase (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase

How do I set a key of a key-value pair using a variable. I want the new entry to have "30" as key with true as a value, so { "30": true }. Now I get { id: true } instead.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
    var id="30";
    ref.child("someChild").update({id:true});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var id="30";
var updatedObj = {};
updatedObj[id] = true;
ref.child("someChild").update(updatedObj);
```

This should do it.

Comment: yep, its the initalising `{}` that i wasn't doing that fixed it.